# How to fetch user who are disabled in LDAP active directory

Tags: java, active-directory, ldap

I have to write java code to find if a particular user in active directory is enabled or disabled.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can inspect the `userAccountControl` bit flag attribute. Its 2nd bit indicates if a user is disabled (see the Remarks section on the attribute's [MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680832%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).)

The easiest is to use a bitwise filter in your LDAP query:

```
(userAccountControl:1.2.840.113556.1.4.803:=2)
```

This filter expression will return only disabled accounts (see more on the usage of bitwise filters in [this article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/269181)).

Comment: The bitwise filter is a great tip!

Comment: Thank you so much for the help. It was great help to me.

Comment: if anyones confused like me, that horrible long number is the Matching rule OID key for 'bitwise AND' https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/adsi/search-filter-syntax